# Spring security login returns 302 when app is hosted on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-security

I have the following security config file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class EvaluariSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // add a reference to our security data source

    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // use jdbc authentication ... oh yeah!!!

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/evaluator/**").hasRole("EVALUATOR")
                        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                                .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .and()
                        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/authenticateTheUser")
                        .and()
                        .csrf()
                            .disable()
                            .cors();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the login works fine when running locally but when I host the app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it sometimes responds with the 302 http code. It's important to say that this is not happening all the time but it's quite annoying when it does. At the moment the app is not working over https yet (it's http).

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: It doesn't just respond "with 302", you get at a minimum a `Location` header that is very important for understanding what's happening. (You also shouldn't disable CSRF with cookie authentication.)

Comment: where is the code for `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` where are your complete debug logs?